# Select top n from different categories

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

So I want to select the top 10 most sold products, per quarter, per year. Quarter being 1/4 of the year.
example:

year->2017
1st quarter: top 10 sold products

i would want this kind of output: (where key->ProductKey, ProductVolume->Count of sales of that product, Quarter->Number of the quarter in question, Year->Year in question.

|Key|ProductVolume|Quarter|Year|
.......
....

2nd quarter: top 10 sold products
...
year->2016
1st quarter: top 10 sold products
2nd quarter: top 10 sold products

```
SELECT s.ProductKey as [Key],
    COUNT(s.ProductKey) as [ProductVolume],
    datepart(q, s.OrderDate) as [Quarter],(yyyy, s.OrderDate) as [Year]
FROM (Select p.ProductKey,
             s.OrderDate,
             row_number() over(PARTITION BY datepart(q, s.OrderDate)
                order by 
                p.ProductKey desc) as rn
      FROM Sales as s 
      INNER JOIN SalesProduct as sp
          ON sp.SalesKey=s.SalesKey
      INNER JOIN Product as p
          ON p.ProductKey=sp.ProductKey
      ) as s
WHERE datepart(yyyy, s.OrderDate) 
    BETWEEN YEAR(getdate())-2 AND YEAR(getdate())
GROUP BY datepart(q, s.OrderDate), datepart(yyyy, s.OrderDate), s.ProductKey
```

this is the result I'm obtaining right now, all the results...

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue660.png)

The image above represents the result of this query's, that are the layout of the tables that i'm using in the inner joins.

```
Select top 1 * from Product;
  Select top 1 * from Sales;
  Select top 1 * from SalesProduct;
```

Comment: Top 10 measured by what? The only order by I see is ProductKey, but that doesn't make much sense as a top 10 (unless you want to see how the newest 10 products perform historically). Also can I ask why bother typing `yyyy` when you could type `year`?

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server? And can you truly measure sales by just counting rows? Does your sales table not have a quantity column? Or if someone buys 6 of the same product you insert 6 rows into the sales table?

Comment: The SQLServer Version is Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169, i edited the question so it can be more specific of what the issue is and what i'm trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordered by sales value per product per quarter+year.

```
DECLARE @Sales TABLE (
    SalesKey INT,
    OrderDate DATETIME
)

DECLARE @SalesProduct TABLE (
    SalesKey INT,
    ProductKey INT,
    UnitPrice MONEY,
    OrderQuantity TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @Sales(SalesKey,OrderDate) SELECT 1, '2018-05-18'
INSERT INTO @Sales(SalesKey,OrderDate) SELECT 2, '2018-05-18'

INSERT INTO @SalesProduct(SalesKey,ProductKey,UnitPrice,OrderQuantity) SELECT 1,123,3.50,1
INSERT INTO @SalesProduct(SalesKey,ProductKey,UnitPrice,OrderQuantity) SELECT 1,125,3.50,1
INSERT INTO @SalesProduct(SalesKey,ProductKey,UnitPrice,OrderQuantity) SELECT 2,123,2.50,5

SELECT *
FROM (
    Select
        datepart(year, s.OrderDate) AS [Year],
        datepart(q, s.OrderDate) AS [Quarter],
        sp.ProductKey,
        sum(sp.OrderQuantity) AS [TotalOrdered],
        sum(sp.UnitPrice * sp.OrderQuantity) AS [TotalValue],
        row_number() over(PARTITION BY datepart(year, s.OrderDate),datepart(q, s.OrderDate) order by sum(sp.OrderQuantity) desc) as [Row]
    FROM @Sales as s 
    INNER JOIN @SalesProduct as sp ON sp.SalesKey=s.SalesKey
    WHERE datepart(yyyy, s.OrderDate) BETWEEN YEAR(getdate())-2 AND YEAR(getdate())
    GROUP BY datepart(year, s.OrderDate),datepart(q, s.OrderDate),sp.ProductKey
) dat
WHERE dat.[Row]<=10
```